How do I fill this hole around radiator pipes between my attic flooring and 2nd floor ceiling?
How do I fill in this hole so that the filling doesn't fall in? The pipes are for a radiator and they lead from the attic floor down through the 2nd floor. I do not want to use expanding foam because I have parrots that can die from the fumes it gives off. Preferably I'd like for it to not stand out too much but I'll take all advice.


What's the concern about the filling falling in?

It's just that if it falls in, there wills till be a hole. I don't necessarily want to fill in the hole bit rather just cover it in a way that doesn't look terrible. If there is a cavity after being covered it's not a big deal to me

Do you own this abode, or is it a rental?

Kinda both. Rent but parents are the homeowners. I can make changes if I need/want.

Based on the limited view of the pipes, is there a chance you could simply cover them with a box (think: a box with back and bottom sides removed)?

One solution: Take a piece of cardboard, cut a hole in the middle of it the same diameter as the pipe, cut a line from edge to hole, use that line to wrap this around the pipe.
